# Why isn't registerSounds called in my mod?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have an event handler in a class designated for sounds like

```
public class Sounds
{
    public static SoundEvent magicWand;

    public void registerSounds(Register<SoundEvent> event)
    {
       IForgeRegistry<SoundEvent> registry = event.getRegistry();

       magicWand = new SoundEvent(new ResourceLocation(MagicWandMod.MODID, 
                     "magic_wand"));

       registry.registerAll(magicWand);
    }    
}
```

but that is never called. Why not?

The class Sounds is registered to the event bus from the common proxy exactly like (my working) capabilities handler.

```
public class CommonProxy
{    
    public void init()
    {
        CapabilityManager.INSTANCE.register(MagicWand.IMagicWandPlayer.class, new MagicWand.MagicWandPlayerStorage(),
                new MagicWand.MagicWandPlayerStorage.Factory());

        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new CapabilityHandler());
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new Sounds());
    }    
}
```

The common proxy is registered from my mod class like

```
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = MagicWandMod.MODID)
@Mod(modid = MagicWandMod.MODID, version = MagicWandMod.VERSION)
public class MagicWandMod
{
    public static final String MODID = "magicwandmod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    public static Item magicwand = new MagicWand();

    @SidedProxy(clientSide = "proxies.CommonProxy", serverSide = "proxies.CommonProxy")
    public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        proxy.init();
    }
}
```

(I get suspicious from the fact that I have to call that init function in the CommonProxy manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `@SubscribeEvent` annotation.

```
public class Sounds
{
    public static SoundEvent magicWand;

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void registerSounds(Register<SoundEvent> event)
    {
       IForgeRegistry<SoundEvent> registry = event.getRegistry();

       magicWand = new SoundEvent(new ResourceLocation(MagicWandMod.MODID, 
                     "magic_wand"));

       registry.registerAll(magicWand);
    }
}
```